# How to avoid adding empty username and password to my database?

Tags: java, sql, unit-testing, exception, junit

When i try testing my add user method with an empty username and password. It still adds the users to my database without username and password. How can i check if my username || password is empty?

I tried this:

```
public boolean addUser(String userName, String password) throws Exception {
        //Checking if the username or password are empty
        if(userName == null || password == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("username or password can't be empty");
        }

        String sql = "insert into user(username,password) values(?,?) ";
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Test for `userName == null || userName.trim().length() < 1`. This way you prevent invalid inputs, and don't even need a library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string could be the "empty" string or contain white space (ie spaces) which could cause it to fail.

Instead use something like:

```
if(userName == null || userName.isBlank()) 
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("username can't be empty");
}

// repeat test for password
```

Comment: Doesn't `.isBlank()` return false for white spaces? It sees them as text right? Or am I wrong

Comment: You're wrong; a trivial one-liner test would have verified that. You'll learn more that way ;)

Comment: It makes no sense to disallow a password consisting of a bunch of whitespace. Either add rules (e.g. "8 or more"), or don't. But, "Cannot be all whitespace", as only rule? No threat model that makes any sense could possibly end up with that conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
if(userName == null || password == null || userName.isBlank() || password.isBlank()) 
{
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Username or Password can't be empty"); 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).